# docker-compose doesn't work without root privilege when a base image is an operating system

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

docker-compose doesn't work without root privilege when base image is operating system such as debian and ubuntu.

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:12-slim

RUN echo "hi"
```

And below is my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:

  service1:
    build: .
```

The error is caused by 'RUN' in the Dockerfile.

The error message is:
`runc run failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "cgroup" to rootfs at "/sys/fs/cgroup": mount cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup/openrc (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0xf, data: openrc: invalid argument`.

dmesg says:
`cgroup: Unknown subsys name 'openrc'`.

While docker-compose doesn't work without root privilege, docker build works without root privilege.

I tried to build with other images, such as debian, ubuntu, nginx and postgres, however docker-compose fails only when the base image is an operating system such as debian and ubuntu.

Since I'm using openrc, I also set `rc_cgroup_mode="hybrid"` in `/etc/rc.conf`.

Why doesn't docker-compose work only when the base image is an operating system?